# Electric field of cone

Tags: integration

I can easily do it with triple integration, but my brother asked me to do it with the help of single integration, I cant work it out. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: He's family, you are allowed to hit him.

Comment: The body of your Question should have a self-contained presentation of the problem you want help with.  The title here hints at what you are asking, and that okay, but it doesn't fulfill the requirement for a complete problem statement in the body.

Comment: Is it a waffle cone, a cup cone, or a sugar cone?  Seriously, what is the configuration of the cone?  How is the charge density distributed?  What kind of nebulous question is this?

Answer (score 3):

With single integration, it's doable for points on the axis of the cone.

Using symmetry, we show that the electric field is directed along the axis of the cone. We can start from a formula for [the electric field of a charged ring](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl34.pdf), subdivide the cone into "very thin" rings and integrate.

We are given the vertex angle $2\theta$, slant height $L$, surface charge density $\sigma$, and [Coulomb's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_constant) (electrostatic constant) $k$.

Let's place the origin of $(x,y)$ coordinates at the apex, so that the cone is symmetric about the $x$ axis.  We compute the electric field $E$ at a point on the cone axis,  at the distance $b$ from the apex.  We already know $dE$ ([the  contribution to the field from a thin ring](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl34.pdf)):
$$
dE = {k(x+b)dQ \over ((x + b)^2 + (x \tan\theta)^2)^{3/2}}
$$
where the charge $dQ$ of the ring is
$$
dQ = \sigma\cdot dA = {2\pi\sigma y\, dx\over\cos\theta}
={2\pi\sigma (x\tan\theta)\, dx\over\cos\theta}.
$$
Combining the above we find
$$
E = \int dE= {2\pi\sigma k \sin\theta\over\cos^2\theta}
\int_0^{L\cos\theta}{(x + b) x\over((x + b)^2 + (x \tan\theta)^2)^{3/2}} dx
$$

Here is a WolframAlpha command to evaluate the indefinite integral:

```
integrate (x+b)x/((x+b)^2+(xt)^2)^(3/2) dx
```

It is not pretty, but it's single integration nonetheless. (We denoted $t=\tan\theta$.)

Comment: It has vertex angle 2θ, slant height L, and surface charge density σ. Can you work out the math?